# WLAN0 not found on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, hp

Hey guys im new to Ubuntu so i installed Ubuntu 16.04 onto DOS OS of my HP.

Legacy support is Enabled.Security Boot Disabled in the BIOS Settings.

When i go to the additional driver i get nothing except the default Unknown one.
The output i got after running iwconfig is

```
eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

lo        no wireless extensions.

The ouput i got after running lspci -nn is

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:5914] (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:9d03] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:9d14] (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:9d15] (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9d4e] (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
```

Output after running rfkill list all is

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

PLEASE HELP !

Comment: When i ran sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms git i got this,E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: kernel 4.13.0-32-generic

Comment: Do you have a program running for software install or updates?  That would cause the error from your first comment.  Use the second set of commands for kernel 4.13

Comment: Thank you so much @Jeremy31 for the fast response.Wifi is working properly now .Glad to be part of the Ubuntu Community !!